# How can I draw a path with javafx , which has specific coordinates?

Tags: java, javafx, game-physics

I want to develop a game with javafx, where I should be able to shoot a ball. The coordinates of the path shall have the form of a projectile motion, so I want to use a mathematical formula for that: y(x) = (- x² / (2*v0² * cos(phi)²) + tan(phi) * x + y0 (looks like a parabola). If the ball reaches the bottom, it should jump again with a lower y coordinate.  I want to make a for loop which sets the x coordinate like as the continuous variable of the for loop and the result of the formula above as the y coordinate. The problem is, I don't know which classes would provide my method. I thought of putting the whole coordinates to an array, but I don't know if it would work. I also don't know if I would really need a mathematical function. 
So which classes would i need? Is there an easier way ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to make a for loop which sets the x coordinate like as the continuous variable of the for loop and the result of the formula above as the y coordinate.

That sounds like a good way to do it.  (Assuming you are just trying to plot the trajectory.  If you are trying to animate a projectile following the trajectory, then your formula needs to be a function of `t -> (x, y)` ... or you need a different approach.)

> The problem is, I don't know which classes would provide my method.

The `java.lang.Math` class provides the transcendental functions (`cos`, `tan` etcetera).  It also has a `pow` function ... but you would be better of just using multiplication to raise something to the power of 2.

I am guessing that `phi` value is just a constant.  You should be able to [look up its value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) and embed it into your code.  (*UPDATE* - I have been advised that `phi` may be a variable.  Either way, it is not a problem.)

But you won't find an existing class / method that does the whole lot for you.  You have to *write one*.

> Is there an easier way ?

Nope.  (AFAIK)

Comment: "`phi`" here is probably just the initial elevation angle; the Golden Ratio has no immediately obvious connection to projectile motion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that the formula you want to use is not very helpful. It only gives you a static relationship between the x and the y coordinate but completely ignores time. If you want to make your game more realistic you should use some existing physics engine like, e.g., http://www.dyn4j.org/ . There are several of them and I don't know which is the best one to play with JavaFX. For the typical game loop you should have a look at the AnimationTimer class in JavaFX.

Comment: Do you know if i would need this formula when i use a physics engine ? Actually my problem is, that i don't know how i should implement a shoot of a ball

Comment: I'd say no. The dynamic behaviour is modeled with the help of the physics engine. Keyword "Gravity". For more you will have to consult the documentation.